# GAN Generator not producing desired results

Tags: python, tensorflow, convolution, deconvolution, dcgan

I am somewhat new to tensorflow, so if the problem is something obvious then please forgive me. Basically, I am making a generative adversarial network and my generator produces very repetitive tile-like patterns. At the current moment my generator model looks like this

```
def generator(input):
    net = dense_block(input, 1024*4*4, "dense-1")
    net = tf.reshape(net, [-1,4,4,1024])
    net = tf.nn.relu(tf.layers.batch_normalization(net, name="bn1"))
    print ("Dense 1", net.get_shape())
    net = deconv_block(net, 512, [5,5], [1,2,2,1], "SAME", "deconv1")
    net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(net, name="bn2")
    net = tf.nn.relu(net)
    print ("deconv 1", net.get_shape())
    net = deconv_block(net, 256, [5,5], [1,2,2,1], "SAME", "deconv2")
    net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(net, name="bn3")
    net = tf.nn.relu(net)
    print ("deconv 2", net.get_shape())
    net = deconv_block(net, 128, [5,5], [1,2,2,1], "SAME", "deconv3")
    net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(net, name="bn4")
    net = tf.nn.relu(net)
    print ("deconv 3", net.get_shape())
    net = deconv_block(net, channels, [5,5], [1,2,2,1], "SAME", "deconv4")
    net = tf.layers.batch_normalization(net, name="bn5")
    net = tf.nn.tanh(net)
    return net
```

where a dense block consists of this:

```
def dense_block(net, out_dim, name):
    w = init_weights([net.get_shape().as_list()[-1], out_dim], name=name+"-weights")
    b = init_biases(out_dim, name=name+"-biases")
    dense = tf.matmul(net, w) + b
    return dense
```

and the deconv block looks like this:

```
def deconv_block(net, filter_num, kernel_size, stride_size, padding, name):
    shape = [kernel_size[1], kernel_size[0], filter_num, net.get_shape().as_list()[-1]]
    in_shape = net.get_shape().as_list()

    w = init_weights(shape, name)
    b = init_biases(filter_num, name)
    out_shape=[in_shape[0], in_shape[2]*2, in_shape[1]*2, filter_num]

    deconv = tf.nn.conv2d_transpose(value=net, filter=w, strides=stride_size, output_shape=out_shape, padding=padding, name=name)
    deconv = tf.reshape(tf.nn.bias_add(deconv, b), deconv.get_shape())
    return deconv
```

The weight and bias creations are as follows:

```
def init_weights(shape, name):
    return tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.truncated_normal(shape, stddev=0.05), name=name+"-weights")

def init_biases(length, name):
    return tf.get_variable(initializer=tf.constant(0.05, shape=[length]), name=name+"-biases")
```

The loss function and optimizer are:

```
g_loss = tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=D_net2, labels=tf.ones_like(D_net2)))
g_opt = tf.train.AdamOptimizer().minimize(loss=g_loss, var_list=g_params)
```

and I am training all of the parameters in graph "G" as defined by:

```
g_params = [v for v in vars if v.name.startswith('G/')]
```

This does seem to return the correct number of variables.
The network is fed a tensor of size (batch_size, 100), which should start to resemble some scaled up mnist data (scaled to 64x64). What I notice from the errors is that the generator only improves in terms of loss for a couple of epochs and then flatlines. Even if the discriminator is only updates every 50 epochs, the generator does not improve after about 150 epochs

An example output is like this:
[Epoch 500](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MhCgh.png)

I would also like to note that the discriminator does work correctly. I started out with the discriminator being a classification CNN for mnist, and then I basically merged all of the outputs into a single node in order to use it with the GAN.

The other outputs also follow similar tiling patterns, and I am not sure why. If anyone could help it would be great! If you need any more information please let me know.

Comment: Does it do something more interesting if you take out the `relu`s (i.e. make it mostly linear)?

Comment: @AllenLavoie The only difference is that it seems to converge later, but it still produces a tiled pattern

Comment: why would you use strides of [1,2,2,1] and and what happens if you change that to [1,1,1,1] ?  Don't generators also take as input some random noise so that they don't always produce exactly the same thing?

Comment: @wontonimo If I understand it correctly, I have to use strides of [1,2,2,1] because I need to do a fractional slide in order to upsample the image. I am going from a 4x4 "image" to 8x8 all the way up to 64x64. If I don't use the [1, 2, 2, 1] stride the image is not upsampled. Please see https://github.com/vdumoulin/conv_arithmetic. To address your second point, the generator takes 100 integer values that are uniformly distributed between 0 and 1 as the input. It should convert these into something that resembles the mnist dataset.

Comment: If this is the mnist data set right with numbers from zero to nine then the input would be a 1hot encoding of 0 to 9.  What input are you giving it?

Comment: @wontonimo The mnist dataset is the one with the numbers from 0 to 9. For the generator I am giving random numbers which then goes through the deconvolutions to produce an output that it believes is in the mnist data distribution. The discriminator model receives the images produced from the generator and images from the actual dataset and it tries to determine which data is actually from the dataset and which one is not. Correct me if I am wrong, but you might be thinking of conditional GANs with the addition of the one hot encoding along with the random numbers as input for the generator.

Comment: Without having *a specific image* to try and create your generator is left with trying to just fool the discriminator, and for a while it will be easy to do this http://www.evolvingai.org/fooling which looks a lot like your noise output.  Basically, I think your generator goes down a hole of making believable noise and not believable images.

Comment: @wontonimo The generator is not trying to remake a specific image. It is trying to produce images within the distribution of the actual dataset, It does this by fooling the discriminator (the one that can tell if the image is real or fake). Then, using the discriminator's results, the generator updates to try to fool the discriminator. I am not trying to reproduce an image exactly. I am approximating a distribution with this technique. There is no "specific image" to learn. Furthermore, the generator isn't making believable noise because the loss for the discriminator is extremely low.

Comment: Why not try to change the initialization part of your biases from initializer=tf.constant(0.05, shape=[length]) to something like initializer=tf.truncated_normal_initializer(stddev=0.02).